# Unable to auto-detect email address (got 'Wrong@email@none') when executing BuildTools.jar

Tags: git, build-tools

I'm trying to install BuildTools.jar.
When executing `java -jar BuildTools.jar` in Windows Powershell I get the following error message:

> unable to auto-detect email address (got 'Wrong@email@none')

i already tried `git config --global user.email "you@example.com"` & `git config --global user.name "Your Name"`

If i check with `git config --global user.email` I'm getting the correct e-mail but it's still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I couldn't fix the error but I have a work around. Insead of using the Windows powershell I used **Git Bash** and it worked.

Comment: This is likely because the utilities you need are on your PATH in Git Bash but not in Windows Powershell.